# show navigation only in inner pages and not on login/registration pages

Tags: angular, angular6

i am trying to show the navigation-bar only in "inner-pages" of the application and not on login/register pages.

I have created a separate component on `navigation`, and in `app.component.html` I show it

```
<app-navbar *ngIf="navVisible"></app-navbar>
<div class="container">
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

I thought that if i'll use `*ngIf=navVisible` it will work, but it doesn't.

### app.component.ts

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.navVisible = this.authsrv.showNav();
 }
```

### AuthenticationService.ts

```
showNav(): boolean {
    let path = window.location.pathname;
    let page = path.split("/").pop();

    if ((page.trim() === "login") || (page.trim() === "registration") || (page.trim() === "")) {
      return false;
    }
    else
      return true;
  }
```

But it doesn't work when i am going from the login to the inner pages.

I tried the same but in `navbar.component.html & navbar.component.ts`
Can someone explain to me what is wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the value of `nanVisible` is set when the your AppComponent loads (`ngOnInit`), only one time when you start the application.

You can solve it by updating it whenever the route changes:

```
constructor(private router: Router) {
   router.events.subscribe((event) => {
      if (event instanceof NavigationEnd) {
        this.navVisible = this.authsrv.showNav();
      }
    });
}
```

I guess what you want to do is send the current route to your `showNav` method.

Comment: nice. it works! why did you placed that code into the `constructor`, and not in `ngOnInit`  ?

Comment: It's up for you to decide where you want to add your logic. Both work in that case.

Comment: Would it be better to place this event in the `authsrv` that i have created?